# How to correct file and folder alphabetical sorting in Windows

Tags: windows-xp

I know this seems like such a simple problem, but the folder and file sorting whenever I perform `Browse` in any application is always in reverse alphabetical order with folders first and then files (also in reverse alphabetical order). When I select `Arrange Icons By > Type`, the order is corrected, but if I hit `Cancel` or even `Open` a file (this is all performed from `Start > Run`), the incorrect order returns. How can I make the ordering permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Open a folder, make the arrangements you want.

Click "Tools" / "Folder Options".

Click "View" / "Apply to All Folders".

A confirmation message should appear, click "Yes".

Click "OK" to exit.